# How do (or should) two separate modules implement the same external library using the Libraries 2.x API?

Tags: theming

The **Libraries** module exists to make it easier for multiple modules to use the same library, but how is this actually done?

Do Module A and Module B both implement the library using `hook_libraries_info()` and `hook_requirements()`? If so, how do they avoid conflicting with each other? In my experience (trying to use Masonry API and Manual Crop modules), they conflict, even when both use the same namespacing, etc.

Or should a new module (Module C) be created that implements the library, and then Module A and Module B depend on Module C and use `libraries_load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries API set out to separate external libraries from Drupal modules. The first step for that was separating the libraries from the module directories by providing the sites/all/libraries directory. Sadly, the separation between libraries and modules stopped there resulting in the problem mentioned above.

To mitigate the race conditions between hook implementations in different modules Libraries API provides the ability to use *.libraries.info files placed in the sites/all/libraries directories which can provide the same information that is otherwise provided in hook_libraries_info(). While this completes the separation between modules and libraries in theory, we failed to provide a place to download and share these info files, thus leaving everyone on their own with that and - in effect - still requiring contrib module authors to implement hook_libraries_info().

We're trying to fix this situation in https://www.drupal.org/node/773508 so if you are interested in improving this situation please do help out (although that issue might be a little bit out of date, to be perfectly honest).

To specifically answer your question, there really is nothing that can be done but the two module maintainers coordinating so that the two modules provide an identical (or at least a compatible) library definition.

> Or should a new module (Module C) be created that implements the library, and then Module A and Module B depend on Module C and use libraries_load()?

That would IMO at the moment - sadly - be the best solution, but often module maintainers are (understandably) reluctant to go forward with such a proposal.

(Full disclosure: I am the maintainer of the Libraries API module)

Answer (score 2):

The [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module provides [`libraries_load`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!libraries!libraries.module/function/libraries_load/7) which allows on-demand loading of libraries that are in `sites/all/libraries`. Libraries are defined by using [`hook_libraries_info`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21libraries%21libraries.api.php/function/hook_libraries_info/7).

It's a good idea to have a single module that defines `hook_libraries_info()` for a given library. For many modules, this is the primary module for Drupal. Take for instance [Mailchimp](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp) or one of [many](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_stripe) [commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_bitpay) [modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_vantiv).

Alternatively, if you know that this module will be used by one or more modules that have no dependency on each other, you can define just a single module which defines the library and then have each module depend on that one.

As far as `hook_requirements` go, that is entirely up to you. I will say that if you do decide to put a requirement in each individual module, **please** namespace it. Lots of payment modules require the **cURL** extension and drop that requirement into `$requirements['curl']` instead of `$requirements['MYMODULE_curl']` this will cause a problem since requirements do not have an alter hook and a key collision will cause errors. So make sure you do the latter and not the former. However, if you're doing a single module, this wouldn't be a problem as you'd just do `hook_requirements` in it.